# like facebook app page via url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am using facebook like button in my site, if someone click like count of people my site url(http://mydomain.com) will increases 
 [image: see the image 1 i attached]

if you look in the 1st image i attached, there is another link find us on facebook
(https://facebook.com/myapppage [image: image to page not liked automatically])
i want it be liked automatically
just imagine this url is working -> https://facebook.com/myapppage?like=1 
 or 
 true
and and page liked automatically will looks like this [image: image 3] 
is there any solution for this `https://facebook.com/myapppage?like=1` and `https://facebook.com/myapppage?like=true` both not working.

Comment: You cannot make a URL which will automatically like the page when visited. Likes have to be done via clicks on a Like button or from within an application which the user has granted permissions to post likes. This is done so that people are not tricked into liking something which they don't want to like. See the Likejacking section of the Wikipedia article about Clickjacking for more info - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking#Likejacking

Comment: @madebydavid : any help in making it possible using JS sdk? `FB.api`?

Comment: You will need to create an app and authenticate users to post likes for people. From a user's perspective, it would be more complicated for them than just clicking a Like button. Are you sure that is what you want?